# Can employers see who has favorited their job posts?

Tags: discussion, jobs

Are employers able to view users who have favorited their job post(s)?

Whether yes or no, is there any thought into this (e.g. no, we didn't want to hide functionality or yes, we wanted to make connecting easier)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  It's private and only viewable by you.

If personal data is ever shared with an employer, you'll be notified before you take that action, like when you apply or answer a message from an employer.  Unless we explicitly say otherwise, it's safe to assume it's private.

We do have some plans around allowing candidates to follow a company page.  In this case we'll likely give employers anonymous data (how many followers etc...).  But again, if we think there's a good reason to share info on individual users, then it will come with a disclaimer.

Comment: Ah, okay. I had been assuming wrong then. Thanks for the thorough answer :)

Comment: On that same note, is there any way to notify an employer that you're interested besides applying?

Comment: @CarrieKendall Sometimes.  If you look under the apply button, certain jobs will have a link that says "Ask [Company] a question"  I admit, this feature is underdeveloped, but if you want to clarify something before applying, this is a great way to do it.